# Помогите проверить пунктуацию в первом абзаце эссе

Tags: пунктуация

Эстетика, для меня лично, составляет важную часть мироздания. По моим глубоким убеждениям, эстетика должна быть фундаментальной основой, как в индивидуальном, так и в общественном сознании. Эстетикой, по мне, должны быть пронизаны помыслы здорового человека, - “здорового” в оценочном понимании его тенденций, - и его желания. Эстетикой хорошо бы руководствоваться и при градостроительстве, обустройстве быта, выборе одежды и прочем. Эстетику нельзя недооценить, ведь она даже выше этики и нравственности, поскольку является высшей ступенью на пути эволюции сознания и в отличии от их двух служит более высоким целям, чем регулировка поведения единицы в социуме и взаимоотношениям внутри него. Эстетика шагает выше, её цель – облагораживать души, не сковывая их неудобоносимыми бременами обязанностей, традиций и общепринятых правил. Сознание, облагороженное эстетикой, уже не мыслит категориями “можно/нельзя; принято/не принято”, оставляя этот удел этике. Что до нравственности, то без эстетики его просто не существует, потому, как нравственность – это модель эстетического поведения в подлинном смысле, а не морально-этического. Тут очень кстати приходится поговорка – “что естественно, то не безобразно”, -и, следовательно, эстетика мыслит категориями – “естественно/не естественно”, но с поправкой на облагораживание самых естественных явлений. То есть из всего вышесказанного можно вывести тезис о том, что эстетика просто придаёт благовидности естественным вещам. Стало быть, эстетика динамична, жива и гибка, ей чужды всякие “скрепы”, догмы и правила. Стоит добавить, что морально-этический контекст не чужд эстетике, потому, как, она сама является матерью этих явлений.

Comment: А где он заканчивается, первый аб, и есть ли второй?

Comment: это только первый

Comment: аб надо бы разбить на аб.

Comment: быть может! я не силён в этом.

Answer (score 1):

**Почему к сожалению,  в этом тексте сложно проверить пунктуацию.**

1) **Пунктуация основана на грамматике** (без правильной грамматики нет правильной пунктуации), а грамматика здесь далеко не безупречна. Я имею в виду стилевую грамматику, где  должны использоваться  грамматические конструкции, ясно и четко передающие содержание текста.

2) Т**огда я делаю попытку  исправить грамматику**, но это не получается, так как мне непонятна логика мысли. И тогда возникает вопрос: а какова коммуникативная направленность текста, **другими словами, для кого пишется статья?**

3) **Если она рассчитана на массового читателя** с минимальной подготовкой, то он просто ничего не поймет. Такому читателю надо предварительно разъяснять терминологию, заинтересовать его темой, главную мысль выдвинуть на первый план, чтобы ему очень захотелось  прочитать Вашу статью.

**Если же Вы обращаетесь к научному сообществу,** то с такими людьми, как мне кажется, можно обсуждать частные вопросы по этой теме, так как с общими они хорошо знакомы.

Мне очень хотелось Вам помочь, но  я не философ и принадлежу скорее к первой категории читателей.

Comment: Тем не менее, спасибо за отклик!

Comment: Сама тема этики, эстетики, нравственности, безусловно, интересна, поэтому хотелось бы понять модель взаимоотношений  этих категорий, если это будет изложено доступно и кратко.(то есть какие существуют мнения,  что нового предлагаете Вы).  В любом случае  я желаю Вам успеха в продвижении Вашей теории.

Answer (score 1):

> Для меня эстетика составляет важную часть мироздания. По моему
>   глубокому убеждению, она должна быть фундаментом всего - как в
>   индивидуальном, так и в общественном сознании. Эстетикой, на мой
>   взгляд, должны быть пронизаны помыслы всякого здорового человека,
>   “здорового” - в оценочном понимании его склонностей и желаний.
>   Эстетикой важно руководствоваться также в градостроении, в
>   обустройстве быта, в выборе одежды и прочем.
>
> Эстетику нельзя недооценивать, ведь она стоит даже выше этики и
>   нравственности, поскольку является высшей ступенью на пути эволюции
>   сознания и, в отличие от них, служит более высоким целям, чем
>   регулирование поведения индивида в социуме и взаимоотношений внутри
>   него. Эстетика стоит выше, её цель – облагораживать души, не
>   сковывая их бременем обязанностей, традиций и общепринятых правил.
>
> Сознание, облагороженное эстетикой, уже не мыслит категориями “можно -
>   нельзя" или "принято - не принято”, оставляя этот удел этике. Что
>   касается нравственности, то без эстетики её просто не существует,
>   потому что нравственность – это в подлинном смысле модель
>   эстетического поведения, а не морально-этического. Здесь очень кстати
>   приходится поговорка: “что естественно, то не безобразно”. То есть,
>   эстетика требует мыслить категориями “естественно - неестественно”, в
>   направлении облагораживания естественных явлений.
>
> Из всего сказанного можно вывести тезис о том, что эстетика лишь
>   придаёт естественным вещам благовидность. Следовательно, эстетика
>   динамична, жива и гибка, ей чужды всякие “скрепы”, догмы и правила.
>   Можно лишь добавить, что морально-этический контекст не чужд эстетике,
>   потому что сама она является матерью этих явлений.

Что затронуто:

1. Исключил разговорные обороты: потому как, по мне, стало быть, тут, что до.
2. Заменены некоторые обороты. "Для меня лично" мне показалось излишне резким (= вы как хотите, а лично я думаю так) -> для меня. "По моим глубоким убеждениям" - выглядит не как аргумент (я глубоко убеждён в том-то = по моему глубокому убеждению), а как утверждение "мои убеждения глубоки (поэтому верьте мне и в этом)". "Фундаментальной основой" (мне показалось тавтологичным) - фундаментом; то же с "неудобоносимым бременем": то, что становится бременем, неудобоносимо всегда, по определению. "Эстетика мыслит" - мыслить может человек с позиций эстетики. Не совсем логично выведение "следствия" из пришедшейся кстати поговорки. "Эстетика шагает выше" - непонятно направление движения: то ли вверх, то ли по горизонтали на более высоком уровне. Изменил, как понял.
3. Остальное - грамматика и пунктуация; вставлены пропущенные слова.

Answer (score 0):

Эстетика, для меня лично, составляет важную часть мироздания. По моим глубоким убеждениям эстетика должна быть фундаментальной основой как в индивидуальном, так и в общественном сознании. Эстетикой, по-моему, должны быть пронизаны помыслы здорового человека - “здорового” в оценочном понимании его тенденций - и его желания. Эстетикой хорошо бы руководствоваться и при градостроительстве, обустройстве быта, выборе одежды и прочем.

Эстетику нельзя недооценить, ведь она даже выше этики и нравственности, поскольку является высшей ступенью на пути эволюции сознания и, в отличие от них, служит более высоким целям, чем регулировка поведения единицы в социуме и взаимоотношений в нем. Эстетика шагает выше, её цель – облагораживать души, не сковывая их неудобоносимым бременем обязанностей, традиций и общепринятых правил.

Сознание, облагороженное эстетикой, уже не мыслит категориями “можно/нельзя; принято/не принято”, оставляя этот удел этике. Что до нравственности, то без эстетики ее просто не существует, потому что нравственность – это модель эстетического поведения в подлинном смысле, а не морально-этического. Здесь очень кстати поговорка “Что естественно, то не безобразно”, и, следовательно, эстетика мыслит категориями “естественно/не естественно”, но с поправкой на облагораживание самых естественных явлений.

То есть из всего вышесказанного можно вывести тезис: эстетика просто придаёт благовидность естественным вещам. Следовательно, эстетика динамична, жива и гибка, ей чужды всякие “скрепы”, догмы и правила. Стоит добавить, что морально-этический контекст не чужд эстетике, потому что она - мать этих явлений.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не всё так плохо оказалось, как я думал изначально!

Comment: «...ей чужды всякие “скрепы”, догмы и правила. Стоит добавить, что морально-этический контекст не чужд ...»?